# In Selenium with Java, how to uncheck some checkboxes?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, checkbox

How can I write in Selenium with java the code to uncheck one of these checkboxes?
In the original search are displayed checked but I want to uncheck one or two or all three to see less results, this is the displayed search:

Filter results by provider:   [x]Facebook (25911),  [x]Hotmail (7651), [x]Yahoo (11)

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: BTW, this is the 2 ways I am trying but none is working:   

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='custom-checkbox-6']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='custom-checkbox-6']")).click();

Comment: Add the relevant html also

Comment: Get all elements which you wish in collection.  Iterate over it, and then by specific use case, check/uncheck what you wish(with parameters).
driver.findElements() will help you.  I think you must separate this on steps e.g, get all target elements, get desired(by check/uncheck), assert state.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague helped me and it was very easy, here is the way it worked:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("custom-checkbox[label^='Yahoo']"))).click();
```

Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old question but I recently ran into this myself. I did not need to know ahead of time if the box was checked, I just wanted to force it unchecked. The solution I came up with (using Javascript in Node.js) is similar to what I use to call setAttribute:

```
let element = await driver.findElement(By.id("checkBox1"));
if (element != null) {
  await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].checked = false;", element);
}
```

This forces the box to be unchecked regardless of whether or not it was first checked. No clicks required.

Answer (score 0):

Some elements can be really fussy.

Try using .sendKeys(Keys.Return) rather than .click().

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of filter result in List (list of Facebook (25911) , Hotmail(7651) and yahoo, Let say list **B**).

Now iterate for loop on that list of webelements(**B**) and if that element is the same that you want to uncheck then you can have a index of that element(Let say you want to uncheck Hotmail so you will get index **1**) now just using that index get a element using that index in xpath (Ex:- //ul[@ag-id='gallery1']/li["(+i+1)+"]/div/div/h4/a). and click on that element.